# Getting `HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported` when using `openssl s_client`

Tags: ssl, http, heroku

I'm trying to use `openssl s_client` to send a raw HTTPS request.

I type this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect homebrew.herokuapp.com:443
```

After it finishes the SSL pleasantries, I type this:

```
POST http://homebrew.herokuapp.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

But then it closes the connection with this:

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Connection: close
```

I only get this on apps hosted on Heroku. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an absolute URL you issue a request against an HTTP proxy.
To make a request against a HTTP server you need a relative URL. Also, HTTP/1.1 the use a a Host header:

```
 POST / HTTP/1.1
 Host: homebrew.herokuapp.com
```

Comment: Sorry, I get the same error after using `POST / HTTP/1.1` as well. I get the error immediately after that line so I can't even type the second line.

Comment: Use -crlf option. Using CRLF is a must according to the RFC2616, but most servers accept a simple LF too.